# msvc pragma warning omitting 'default' in cpp file

Tags: c++, pragma

I have some `pragma warning (disable : xxx)` in cpp files (not headers):

now if we omit `pragma warning (default : xxx)` in same cpp file, does that warning stay disabled across all cpp files in project or just in this cpp file?

also if we compile multiple projects, does that disabled warning affect all projects? assuming pragma in cpp file only not in headers.

for example, I have:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG   // In release build using CrtDebug functions has no effect!
#define CRT_DBG_REPORT(...) 0
#pragma warning (disable : 6326)    // Potential comparison of a constant with another constant
#pragma warning (disable : 26814)   // The const variable can be computed at compile time
#pragma warning (disable : 26477)   // Use nullptr rather than 0 or NULL
#pragma warning (disable : 4127)    // conditional expression is constant
#pragma warning (disable : 4100)    // unreferenced formal parameter
#else
#define CRT_DBG_REPORT _CrtDbgReportW
#endif // NDEBUG
```

I would like to omit setting back to 'default' but ensure it only disables the warnings for this cpp file.

**edit**

thanks to comment section suggestion...

If we enable `Unity` build, what is the behavior of "undefauled" (only disabled) cpp pragmas? `Project properties -> Advanced -> Unity.`

Comment: I would expect just the .cpp file since each translation unit is compiled separately.

Comment: @downvoter surely has some documentation to back up his downvote?

Comment: @drescherjm, it's probably worth noting that in VS you can enable `Unity` build, which combines multiple 'cpp' files into one for faster compilation. in that case pragams may not work as you suggest. but otherwise yes, I assume the same. `Project properties -> Advanced -> Unity`

Comment: Thanks, I have not heard of that feature until now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the warnings are disabled in the cpp file, they will only affect the lines underneath the pragma (they won't affect other compilation units). Unity builds would probably cause an issue though *(at a guess, can't test this right now)*.

Generally speaking, if you are enabling/disabling warnings via pragmas, this is probably the way to go:

```cpp
#define PUSH_DISABLE_WARNINGS \
  __pragma(warning(push)) \
  __pragma(warning(disable : 6326)) \
  __pragma(warning(disable : 26814)) \
  __pragma(warning(disable : 26477)) \
  __pragma(warning(disable : 4127)) \
  __pragma(warning(disable : 4100))

#define POP_DISABLE_WARNINGS \
  __pragma(warning(pop))
```

and then later on...

```cpp
PUSH_DISABLE_WARNINGS

/* warnings will only be disabled here */

POP_DISABLE_WARNINGS
```

Comment: Nice solution! I do use `#define SUPPRESS(...) __pragma(warning(disable : __VA_ARGS__))` to disable single line, but never come to idea to combine this with `push/pop` and affect entry file. very nice!